# IOS have a report builder generate in PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, report

I have data to generate report that have header footer and content.

In the content have many group when the data in each group over the page area it add new page and write header of group and continued content data

Where can I have lib. or something to do this Task ??

Thanks For Advance.

Add for request code

```
    NSArray *headObject = [uniqueStates allObjects];////Store head of each group
    NSArray *detail; //Store all of data to present in table

    int allData = [detail count]; // Tel amount of all data to show
    /*
    int headGroupline = 1; //Tel amount of head group line
    int footGroupline = 1; //Tel amount of foot group line
    */
    int detailIndex = 0; ///Tel what line we are now
    int detailHeadIndex = 0; ///Tel what group we are now
    int subdetail = 0; // Tel what line on group now

    int aviableLineInpage = 24; // Line avilable in page for data to show

    int allPage = 0; //Sum of all page

    for (; detailIndex < allData; ) {
        allPage++;
        for (int i=0; i < aviableLineInpage;) {

            if (allData - detailIndex == 0) {
                ///ShowgrandTotal
                ........

                detailIndex++;
                i+=25;
            }else{
                if (i == 0) {
                    //Show Head Group
                     ......
                }else{
                    if (subdetail == [[detail filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(buy_date == %@)", headObject[detailHeadIndex]]] count]+1) {
                        detailHeadIndex++;
                        //Show Head Group
                          ..........
                    }else{
                        if (subdetail == [[detail filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(buy_date == %@)", headObject[detailHeadIndex]]] count]) {
                            //Show sum of each group
                               ..........
                            i++;
                            detailIndex++;
                            subdetail++;
                            detailHeadIndex++;
                        }else{
                            //Show data of detail
                            ........................
                            detailIndex++;
                            subdetail++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }

        }//for all line in page
    }//for allData
```

It format is:

date 27/01/2014 
  data1 
  data2
  data3
sum date 27/01/2014

date 28/01/2014
  data1 
  data2
<============if page brake add new page and

date 28/01/2014
  data3
sum date 28/01/2014

grand total........

But it goes

date 27/01/2014 
  data1 
  data2
  data3
sum date 27/01/2014

  data1 
  data2
<============if page brake add new page and

date 28/01/2014
  data3
grand total........

Thanks very much

Comment: so you want to make a pdf based on your data?

Comment: yes I have a data @Retro

Comment: I have generated a dynamic page pdf with different table and different rows using coreGraphics so do you want like this?

Comment: Do you have Idea or code to show me please?
I struck it for 3 days with coreGraphic
But if it have any lib. to do this task it was great thing!!

Comment: Show what you have tried and explain what it does wrong.

Comment: @Wain Now I add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int allData = [detail count]; // Tel amount of all data to show
    /*
    int headGroupline = 1; //Tel amount of head group line
    int footGroupline = 1; //Tel amount of foot group line
    */
    int detailIndex = 0; ///Tel what line we are now
    int detailHeadIndex = 0; ///Tel what group we are now
    int subdetail = 0; // Tel what line on group now

    int aviableLineInpage = 24; // Line avilable in page for data to show

    int allPage = 0; //Sum of all page

    for (; detailIndex < allData; ) {
        allPage++;
        for (int i=0; i < aviableLineInpage;) {

            if (allData - detailIndex == 0) {

                detailIndex++;
                i+=25;
            }else{
                if (i == 0) {

                    if (subdetail == -1) {
                        subdetail = 0;
                    }
                }else{
                    if (subdetail == -1) {

                        subdetail = 0;
                    }else{
                        if (subdetail == [[detail filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(buy_date == %@)", headObject[detailHeadIndex]]] count]) {

                            i++;

                            subdetail = -1;
                            detailHeadIndex++;
                            if (detailHeadIndex == [headObject count] ) {
                                detailIndex++;
                            }
                        }else{

                            detailIndex++;
                            subdetail++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            i++;
            }

        }//for all line in page
    }//for allData
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CGPDFDocumentRef` and the associated functions to create the PDF document and each page it contains. When you create a page (`UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo`) you can get the associated drawing context (`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`). Once you have that you can draw in a number of ways:

1. You could create a view with your header and footer, add content and render it into the view (using its layer)
2. You could draw images and text direct into the context (using CoreText (`CTFrameDraw`))

You need to create the logic to set how much content can fit on any one page and when you need to create a new page.

Also, depending on how you choose to draw content into the context you may need to scale and transform (`CGContextScaleCTM` + `CGContextTranslateCTM`) the context so that your content isn't upside down.

See [this Apple guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-CJBHHJCB).

Comment: Thanks But the PDF I can create it.
For now i scope the code that logic to create each page.
 That I post on Question. 

Thanks for Help

Comment: It may help for you to link a screenshot of what you get and what you expect.